# How do I send a file from postman to node.js with multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman, multer

Windows
Express 4.12.4
Multer 1.0.1
Node v0.10.22

I'm trying to send a file to my node.js server using postman.

I'm attempting to follow the readme [here](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)

Here's what I'm sending with postman:

```
POST /ingest HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 69dd2497-2002-56ed-30a4-d662f77dc0b0
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

Here's what it looks like:
[image]

Here's what it's hitting on node.js

```
var Ingest      = require('../controllers/ingest.js');
var multer      = require('multer');
var upload      = multer({ dest: 'uploads/',fileFilter:function(req,file,cb){
        console.log('file is',file)
        cb(null,true);
    }
});

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.post('/ingest', upload.single('test'), function(req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.body);
        console.log(req.file);
        Ingest.ingestData()
        .then(function (response){
            return res.status(200).json(response);
        });
    });
}
```

When I hit this route with postman I get `{}` for `req.body` and `undefined` for `req.file`.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's where I initialize the `app` that gets passed in to the route file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var cfg = require('./config')();
var passport = require('passport');
var cors = require('cors');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || cfg.port);
var corsOptions = {
    origin: "*",
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Accept', 'x-reset-token', 'x-invite-token', 'x-api-key', 'x-www-form-urlencoded'],
    credentials: true
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Maybe something in there is doing it?

### Edit:

I've even tried

```
var Ingest      = require('../controllers/ingest.js');
var multer      = require('multer');
var upload      = multer({ dest: 'uploads/',fileFilter:function(req,file,cb){
        console.log('file is',file)
        cb(null,true);
    }
}).single('csv');

module.exports = function (app) {

    app.post('/ingest', function(req,res){
        upload(req, res, function(err) {
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            console.log(req.body);
            console.log(req.file);
            Ingest.ingestData()
            .then(function (response){
                return res.status(200).json(response);
            });
        });
    });

}
```

And that didn't help. It doesn't log anything for `err`

Comment: In the screenshot, you are missing `csv` key for filename.

Comment: @hassansin oh, is that what that was for? Post it as an answer and I can accept it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Postman screenshot, the file field name is missing. The key should be `csv` since Multer accepts single file with that name.

Answer (score 17):

Just remove header **Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded** from the postman.

[image]

Comment: Why am i getting down voted. please look clearly that Content - Type is unchecked.

Comment: Well your answer worked for me so I am up-voting you mate.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: thanks lol I was looking for the same and this was the only thing that prevented it from working with multer(nodejs)

Comment: Thank you ! This helped me ! :)

Answer (score 11):

This would help others like me who are searching for a similar answer.

I used a curl request instead of Postman.

```
curl -v -F csv=@file.csv http://localhost/url
```

There seems to be an issue with Postman.

https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/317

> I also have this issue when I use Postman to send file using form-data. The attribute req.file or req.files is always undefined. If anyone has used Postman and was able to retrieve the file using req.file or req.files, please comment.

Comment: thanks, i have the same problem with postman, spent lot of time on it, and didnt success

Answer (score 0):

Updating from Postman version 5.5.3 to version 8.0.7. solved the issue for me. Maybe related to this [problem](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2651) fixed in version 7.

Answer (score -1):

`Multer` looks for the file named 'single'. So if you add the key as 'single' in postman `form-data` it should work